# Visual Studo 2012 - C#: Display multiple lines in line chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, linechart

I am trying to display 2 lines in a line chart. If I display them separately, it worked properly. Problem is that when I tried to display both of them, I just could see only 1 line.
This is my code to add point to the series

```
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            output = float.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[9].Value.ToString())/maxOutput;
            float prediction = network.run(input, output)*maxOutput;
            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[10].Value = prediction;

            chartComparision.Series["Reality"].Points.AddY(output);
            chartComparision.Series["Prediction"].Points.AddY(prediction);

        }
```

I'm sorry I haven't have enough reputation to post image, [this is the link to the image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96570708/chart.PNG).
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the scale of your `Reality` data? From that image it looks like it's there, but it's all along the bottom, at the X-axis.

Comment: It looks like as you iterate through your for loop it is overwriting the value for output, rather than appending new data to it. When the loop finishes you're left with only the last value for output.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline OMG, I didn't pay attention to the scale. You are my savior! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Greg I inserted values to separate series so I will have 2 lines. And by default, the chart does not overwrite values, it automatically appends values.